# How to instanciate custom classes (not activities or fragments) before sending events using Greenrobot event bus

Tags: android, event-bus

I'm writing an android app right now using EventBus greenrobot. For example I have an Activity it's a publisher in our situation and we have some custom class - just simple class and it is subscriber. Let's assume that I'm posting event from activity. As far as i understand we don't have any instance of custom class, because right now it's decoupled from activity. So how can I make to have instance of this class always.

Or may be I'm  using Eventbus incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you post an event, the subscriber has to be ready to get that event doing:

eventBus.register(this)

So that class always has to be initialized (from your Activity or from some other part in your app)